# Azure Web Job Code looking for idyunnoo.f2h folder

Tags: azure, web-applications, webjob

I have a continuous web job and we have a certificates which are included as part of build. Build contains certificates inside a certificates but I got a  below error

Could not find file

> D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\MyWebJobProject\idyunnoo.f2h\Certificates\INT\XXXX.p12

in actual build certificates folder present in  MyWebJobProject  folder , folder structure is

> MyWebJobProject\ Certificates\INT\XXXX.p12

I am not sure why code is checking inside **idyunnoo.f2h** folder and not sure when this kind of folders will create in azure web job

in my code we using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory to find path of Certificate

Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Certificates\Production\XXXX.p12");

Answer (score 0):

Take my screenshot as an example, when you post your webjob, make sure that your certificates folder is under the Debug folder, and then package the Debug folder. There is no problem with your code. I tested it with your method. It should be the wrong path for the certificate.

[image]

[image]

[image: Run successfully]

Your folder structure is `MyWebJobProject\Certificates\INT\XXXX.p12`, So you should build your program. And rename `Debug` to  `MyWebJobProject`, then compress files into zip format for upload. Make sure `Certificates` folder is under `MyWebJobProject` folder.

Comment: Thanks @jason ,i will try and check it

Comment: @JagadeeshB Has your problem been resolved, do you need further assistance?

Comment: Yes, My Problem Solved Thanks !